# Is it more optimal to call OpenGL glGenXXX functions for arrays than single elements?

Tags: opengl

I have just started learning OpenGL and I was wondering if there is any benefit in calling functions like `glGenVertexArrays` or `glGenBuffers` passing them an array compared to calling them multiple times (considering the actual call negligible). I tried to find details about what these functions are doing behind the scenes but I didn't find anything helpful.

As an example, I want to know if something like

```
GLuint vbo[2];
glGenBuffers(2, vbo);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices1), vertices1, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices2), vertices2, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

has any significant *hidden* benefit over this other way

```
GLuint vbo0, vbo1;

glGenBuffers(1, &vbo0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo0);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices1), vertices1, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &vbo1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo1);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices2), vertices2, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should try to minimize the number of OpenGL instructions.

Comment: @Rabbid76 That makes sense, but I was looking for a more insightful answer. That's not always practical and sometimes can hinder readability.

Comment: That was not an answer it was a comment. [`glGenBuffers`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenBuffers.xhtml) does not create an object, it just reserves name-ids for objects, the operation is probably _cheep_. Most like you use `glGenBuffers` just at initialization and not continuously in each frame, so there is no relevant downside. Anyway, the OpenGL specification just specifies _what_ and not _how_. The OpenGL driver is written by the hardware vendor and the only one who knows more about it.